# Showing two listings in a table side-by-side

Tags: tables, listings, two-column, columns

I wonder is there any possibility to show two different listings in one table side by side?
Here is my code that only show one listening but how can I embed it in a table and another one?

**EDIT: Even I have tried the mentioned links on below, I get a few errors while compiling the file. I also post my edited LaTeX code.**

```
    \documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={[AspectJ]Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}

class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread

    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

&

\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={[AspectJ]Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}

class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread

    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to show is :
[image]

Comment: Just put them in two minipages or two tabular p-column entries, no special package or coding is needed.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/displaying-two-xml-listings-side-by-side and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118437/including-html-code-side-by-side-in-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David said to do.  In this case, I placed the result in a `tabular`.  I also made the listings in `\tiny`, so as to make two side-by-side listings fit in the margin width.

In my case, I also placed them in boxes beforehand, so that my `tabular` code would look nice:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\stackinset{l}{-5pt}{t}{13\llength}{$\bullet$}{\listingA} &
\stackinset{l}{-5pt}{t}{ 7\llength}{$\bullet$}{\listingB} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

EDITED to add little black circle to each listing.  In this case, I superimposed them on the listing box with a `\stackinset`, defining the length of `\llength` to correspond to one line spacing in the tiny listing.  Thus, a command like

```
\stackinset{l}{-5pt}{t}{13\llength}{$\bullet$}{\listingA}
```

indicated to place the bullet 13 lines down on the first listing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\llength
\llength=1.38ex\relax
\begin{document}

\clearpage

\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{minipage}{1.9in}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\tiny\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={[AspectJ]Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}

class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread

    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
}
\savestack{\listingA}{\box0}

\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{minipage}{1.9in}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\tiny\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={[AspectJ]Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}

class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread

    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
}
\savestack{\listingB}{\box0}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\stackinset{l}{-5pt}{t}{13\llength}{$\bullet$}{\listingA} &
\stackinset{l}{-5pt}{t}{ 7\llength}{$\bullet$}{\listingB} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! One tiny question is that is it possible to draw a circle next to a code [like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/i0tx74pxw09gm20/Capture.GIF) ?

Comment: @Hakan Can you be more specific?  What size circle, filled or unfilled?  Color?  Location?

Comment: Sure I can, a filled black circle whose size is very small. Did you notice my circle drawn in the related link?

Comment: @Hakan  I revised the code.  Is that what you seek?  If not quite, you can play with the 2nd and 4th arguments of `\stackinset` to move the dot around.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, I am getting an error on line 7 :" \newlength\llength\newlength\lwidth " this says that "File `stackengine.sty' not found." How can I get rid of this?

Comment: @Hakan You need to download the stackengine package, from which the `\stackinset` macro comes.  It is at http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine.  You can place the .sty file in your working directory, until you figure out how to install the package.

Answer (score 2):

Your example generated errors because `color` was not loaded, but other than that it basically worked. You don't need the `tabular` just two `minipages are sufficient. Some of your lines are too ong to fit side by side, but that's a separate issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={[AspectJ]Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}

class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread

    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%%
\hfill
%&
%
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={[AspectJ]Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}

class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread

    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
%\\

%\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! whereas I need a tabular property to distinguish two different codes in one big table.

Comment: Yes if you are using a table anyway you can put them in a tabular (but then you don't need the minipages you can put the listings envirinment straight in the tabular cells if you use p{...} instead of l in the column specifiers.

Comment: But I also want to use bullets in my tabular, as we talked about it in the first post's comments with Steven. How can be possible to use multiple bullets in a listing then?

Comment: @Hakan but that is an entirely separate issue which would be best asked as a separate question, Adding bullets to the listing is the same whether the listings are full page or 2 side by side. The question here was about putting two listings side by side and it's misleading to future readers if you then ask a different question in the comments which force the answers to load extra packages and more complicated code. The original question doesn't require any more code than putting two images or two paragraphs side by side.

Comment: Allright you are totally right , I will arrange another question for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please explain why I am getting the error saying 'Missing number, treated as zero \begin{lstlisting}' in this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8kirfze2evbzabn/tabular.txt)

Comment: @Hakan a `p` column is essentially a minipage it needs a width argument. `p{.45\textwidth}` or p{3cm}` or something.

Comment: I am trying to eliminate minipages in my code, I have put my codes into cells and deleted all the minipages. I still get this error.

Comment: @Hakan the link still shows `\begin{tabular}{|p|p|}` which as I say above is wrong

Comment: according to the edited link I now have this error :'Missing \endgroup inserted morekeywords={class,run}]'

Comment: I just changed ll in your linked example to `\begin{tabular}{|p{.4\textwidth}|p{.4\textwidth}|}` and it runs without error. If you have a new problem please ask a new question. not in comments